# How do I convert my while loop to a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, netbeans

I am a beginner coder using Netbeans Java. I have created a code that initially asks how many gallons are in your gas tank. Then, it will have a while loop asking how many miles you will be traveling for this first run and how fast are you traveling. This will repeat with a while loop until you input '0' to stop adding trips. I am stumped on how to convert this while loop into only using For loops. I would greatly appreciate the assistance. Here is my code that has while loops.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int tank;
            double miles;
            double speed;
            double totalMiles = 0.0;
            int choice;
            double time;
            double totalTime = 0.0;
            double fuelConsumption;

            System.out.print("How many gallons of gas is in your tank (Integer 1-15)? ");
            tank = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%s%d%s\n\n" , "You have ", tank , " gallons of gas in your tank.");

            System.out.print("Are you going on a trip (1 = Yes or 0 = No)? ");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            while (choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("How many miles are you traveling? ");     // miles 
                miles = input.nextFloat();

                System.out.print("What is your speed for this run (MPH)? ");      // speed
                speed = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("\n");


                totalMiles = totalMiles + miles;
                time = (miles/speed);
                totalTime += (time*60);
                fuelConsumption = (20*(tank/totalMiles));

                System.out.print("Is there another leg in your trip (1 = Yes or 0 = No)? ");    // asking another leg
                choice = input.nextInt();

                if (choice == 0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%s%5.2f%s\n","Your data for this trip is: \n"
                            + "You traveled a total of about ", totalMiles , " miles.");
                    System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s\n" , "You traveled about " , totalTime , " minutes.");

                    if (fuelConsumption >= 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your car has enough gas to return.");
                        break;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your car will need more gas to return.");
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }

}
```

}

Comment: Repeating the classic Stack-Overflow response: *why?* A `for` loop makes no sense here, because you can't iterate over the number of times the user doesn't press 0, unless you can predict the future.

Comment: @lealceldeiro You can just do it with `for (;choice == 1;)`, you don't need another variable, all 3 parts of a `for` loop are optional (though clearly he should _not_ do this over a `while`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a use case for a for loop, where we iterate over a known number of elements for do a known number of iterations. Like, repeat 10 times or such.

Technically it can be solved with a for loop, but that is abusing the concept a bit. The while loop is a perfect fit for that task.

Comment: This is the correct answer, OP! YOu could hack a for-loop, but why? It's the wrong tool for the job.  You're already using the right tool.

Comment: Yeah he definitely should not use a `for` loop, but it is kind of funny that the way to convert it to the equivalent `for` is the same number of characters anyway: `for (;choice == 1;)` and `while (choice == 1)`.

Comment: Thank you, I am sure that I can turn this in a way of where I can ask the user the number of the trips they would like to take in order to use that as the number of repetition needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a place to use a for-loop, you use a for loop for something like this:

```
printAmount = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < printAmount; i++) {

   System.out.println("Hello World"); 

}
```

Here you are using the for loop to print "Hi" for the amount in printAmount.

Your case is different: You want the while-loop to repeat while the input is "1" so you use a WHILE-loop.